# Plist - iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, plist

I've created a plist and filled it with data by modifying the myPlist.plist file directly. How can i read values from it and display them on the output.
I'm working with grouped tables and i want to fill the data of the cells from the plist i created earlier.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Check my answer. Hope that helps u.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't format the code properly in the answer.

Comment: -1 dude check out this link http://www.google.com/search?q=read+values+from+plist+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @Kattupoochi i'm too lazy to google stuff :P i deserve your -1 !!

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the content as an `NSDictionary`, then this is how you have to access it from the plist:

```
NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
NSLog(@"%@", myDict);
```

Obtain the data in an array if you have stored the data as `NSArray`. 
To display it in the tableview use the following code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Write the above code inside `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: This will work as well with plist created with the plist editor as long as the top object is an array, dictionary or set.